# Preventing mobile browsers from scrolling input into view

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, mobile, viewport, user-experience

I have a form with form items "above the fold." On a similar page, when tapping the input, the phone does not scroll, while on the other page it does.

When the virtual keyboard is disabled, the screen is very jarringly jerked down below the original input even.

I suspect it has to do with the height of the page.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior? If not, is there a way to return the screen precisely to the position it was in on focus out?

Currently, I gently scroll to the top, but I'd rather not mess with the user experience like that.